# Removing a element from an array list without using libraries. Java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have implemented a function which removes an element from an array list. I should not the ArrayList libraries! See my code below:

```
/**
 * removes a LendItem at a specified (index) position.
 * This functions returns the item removed from the list or null if no such item exists. This
 * function leaves no gaps, that means all items after the removed item are shifted one position.
 * @param list is the item to be removed
 * @param n is the index of the item to be removed
 * @return the removed item
 */

public static LendItem remove(LendItemArrayList list, int n) {

    if (list.next == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    if (n < 0 || n > list.INITIAL_SIZE) {
        return null;
    }

    LendItem itemToBeRemoved = list.lendItems[n]; // itemToBeRemoved is the item which has the index n, which we want to remove from the list.
    int i;
    for (i = n; i < list.next - 1; i++) { // iterate through the list, starting where the index of the itemToBeRemoved is. 
        list.lendItems[i] = list.lendItems[i + 1];
    }

    list.lendItems[i] = null;
    list.next--;
    return itemToBeRemoved;
}
```

and here is the class :

```
public class LendItemArrayList {

    int INITIAL_SIZE = 20;
    boolean resizeable = false;
    LendItem[] lendItems = new LendItem[INITIAL_SIZE];
    int next = 0;
}
```

I have tested my functions with a few test methods which have been provided, and i am only failing one of them. Specifically the test is called:

```
removeNonExistingElement
```

and it fails like this:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 10 elements have been added, next should be 10 (no changes) but found 9.

**EDIT:** 
Added the add() function.

```
public static boolean add(LendItemArrayList list, LendItem p) {

    if (list.next == list.lendItems.length) {
        if (list.resizeable == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (list.next == list.lendItems.length) {
        if (list.resizeable == true) {

            LendItem[] resizedList = new LendItem[list.lendItems.length*2]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < list.next; i++) {                           
                resizedList[i] = list.lendItems[i];                         
            }

            list.lendItems = resizedList;

        }
    }

    list.lendItems[list.next++] = p;                                        
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave this as it is, as it checks if the indices are out of range.

```
if (n < 0 || n >= list.INITIAL_SIZE) {
                return null;
    }
```

Next, add this line of code:

```
if (list.lendItems[n] == null) {
            return null;
        }
```

Afterwards, you may or may not add the if statement which checks if the given list is empty. It makes no difference unless it is required to be used.

```
if (list.next == 0){
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (n < 0 || n > list.INITIAL_SIZE) {
```

To this:

```
if (n < 0 || n >= list.INITIAL_SIZE) {
```

`>=` means greater or equal. If `n == list.INITIAL_SIZE`, then that item can't be removed either, because since indices start with 0, the last value in a list has an index of size - 1. It's one of those things that hurt your brain when you start programming.

Comment: You mean, comparing the index with the initial size instead of the actual size isn’t an error in the first place?

Comment: @Holger With the code provided, the initial size doesn't change, but if you assume the size changes in some hidden `add` method than that is a good point.

Comment: @DoubleDouble: exactly. So you can repeatedly invoke the remove method with a positive index being smaller than the `INITIAL_SIZE` until the actual size (which has the absurd name `next`) becomes even smaller than that index, effectively removing items at other indices…

Comment: @Holger `next` is the number of actual values in the list (*which I agree is a bad name*), while `INITIAL_SIZE` is the size of the backing array (*initially full of null values*). The size of the backing array never changes as far as we know, so `n` can never be greater than `INITIAL_SIZE`. `next` will not go negative via `remove` because if it is `0` it returns `null`

Comment: @DoubleDouble: I already updated my comment. It’s not going negative, but down to zero. Just think about what happens, if I call `remove(9)` ten times. Afterwards, `next` will be zero… A check for the validity of a remove index should incorporate the actual size, not the size of the backing array.

Comment: @DoubleDouble I have added the add() method which i have implemented.

Comment: @Holger I see. `list.next--;` is called regardless of whether it actually removed a value. Your solution would be best in that case.

Comment: @Holger I agree that that is good practice in general, but not in all cases. What if the array represents, say 10 fixed boxes. In this case removing an item from the list would represent clearing a box. Clearing a box that is already empty would be a legitimate statement in this case and comparing against the initial size would be the preferred solution. (since you don't want the indices to be reassigned).

Comment: @Xander The problem is the `next` variable and whatever it is really meant to represent. You could add items to box 1 and 2, resulting in `next` value of 2, and then clear items in box 5, resulting in `next` value of 1, but with values still in boxes 1 and 2. I can't think of a reason where you would want that.

Comment: @Xander: that doesn’t harmonize with the existence of a `next` pointer, used by the `add` method. If you have ten fixed boxes without a changeable size, you can’t provide `add` and `remove` methods at all, but only `set` and `get` methods, in other words, then you have what arrays are already themselves. Once you have `add` and `remove` methods, you have a mutable size and *must* use that mutable size consistently.

Comment: @Holger You are right about that, but I think that's just a naming issue.